# Is there any profiler available in recent Lazarus IDE (2.2.6)?

Tags: optimization, profiling, freepascal, lazarus

I'm checking out options listed in https://wiki.freepascal.org/Profiling :

### gprof

On Windows, it is missing unspecified libraries (MinGW? CygWin?) with no clear installation instructions.

On Linux, I get a linking error:

> /usr/bin/ld.bfd: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc_nonshared.a(atexit.oS): in function 'atexit':(.text+0x14): undefined reference to '__dso_handle'

### Valgrind

didn't try it yet, AFAIK it's more of a memory leak detection tool than a profiler. Can it really generate proper profiling data?

### [FPProfiler](https://wiki.freepascal.org/FPProfiler)

The [SVN repo](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/fpprofiler/?root=fpcprojects) seems to be down.

The [git repo](https://github.com/graemeg/fpprofiler) was updated 13 years ago. Upon inspection, I see no package file (lazprof.lpk) in it at all.

### [LazProfiler](https://wiki.freepascal.org/LazProfiler)

The code is 4 years old and [doesn't seem to work](https://github.com/PascalRiekenberg/LazProfiler/issues/5) with latest IDEs.

Did anyone get a working profiler in recent Lazarus?

Comment: Note: there is also https://github.com/ase379/gpprofile2017, though it seems to be Delphi-only.