# How to get code coverage with FPCUnit / Lazarus?

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, lazarus

Context: I need to update some Lazarus code, and I figured I'd write unit tests for it before I start changing anything. However, it's hard to estimate the completeness of tests which were written after the code, so I thought of code coverage as a simple completeness metric.

I have found [this repo](https://gitlab.com/ccrdude/laz-codecoverage-helper/) which seems to do exactly what I need (it adds a coverage tab to FPCUnit), but unfortunately the code in that repository fails to build with Lazarus 2.2.6:

> CodeCoverage.SynGutter.pas(98,19) Error: Identifier not found "FoldView"

Are there any hints on how to get Lazarus CodeCoverage Helper working, or any alternatives?

PS. Helping out with my attempt at getting code coverage with [debugger breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76500749/4350586) would also be appreciated.

Comment: According to [SynEditMarkupHighAll](https://github.com/alrieckert/lazarus/blob/master/components/synedit/syneditmarkuphighall.pp)'s last commit date get yourself a Lazarus IDE from 2015 or earlier.

Comment: @AmigoJack Nice find, but Lazarus 1.4 is way too old to compile anything remotely recent. It has no modern features such as high DPI support, on-the-fly UI translation, or some components such as multi-select-capable lists.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76399149/4350586